# How do i popup a context menu with custom command items in a Select tool OnMouseDown (Right Click) with VB .Net?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, development

This should be simple... I am converting VBA customization to VB .NET in VS 2008 Express Edition.
In VBA i have a custom selection tool. Aside from just selecting features, when OnMouseDown receives Button = 2 parameter (right click) I popup a context menu with some macro items that call various other procedures.

I need some help with making this work in .Net...

I used the ESRI .NET sample project to get the feel for this and i am sure i can re-create the select tool but i am having problems with the context menu. I would also like to know how to call procedures when user clicks the context menu item.

```
Private Sub UIToolControl1_MouseDown(ByVal button As Long, _
    ByVal shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)

Dim pLayer As ILayer
Dim pContextMenu As ICommandBar
Dim pAppPosition As IWindowPosition
Dim pPoint As POINTAPI

If pMxDoc.SelectedLayer Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Select a layer in the TOC!": GoTo ep
End If

Select Case button
Case 1
Set pLayer = pMxDoc.SelectedLayer
If pLayer Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "You must select 1 feature layer in the TOC!": GoTo ep
End If

If Not TypeOf pLayer Is IGeoFeatureLayer Then
MsgBox "You must select 1 feature layer in the TOC!": GoTo ep
End If

Set m_pPoint = _
    pActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(x, y)
m_bIsMouseDown = True
Case 2
'on right click = popup
Set pContextMenu = CommandBars.Create("Go2Grid", esriCmdBarTypeShortcutMenu)

Set pAppPosition = Application

' Add 3 built in commands to the new context menu using the
' built-in ArcID module.

pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "New Feature Class", 8, _
    "Normal.Module1.CreateNewFeatureClass"
pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "Delete Layer", 13, _
    "Normal.Module1.DeleteFeatureClass"
pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "Copy To...", 20, _
    "Normal.ThisDocument.CopyFeatures"
pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "Draws Around...", 26, _
    "Normal.ThisDocument.DrawsAroundFeatures"
pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "Clear Tool", 10, _
    "Normal.ThisDocument.ClearCurrentTool"
pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem "Delete Features", 13, _
    "Normal.Module1.DeleteFeatures"

' Popup the menu.

pPoint.x = x
pPoint.y = y
ClientToScreen pActiveView.ScreenDisplay.hwnd, pPoint

pContextMenu.Popup pPoint.x, pPoint.y
Case Else
GoTo ep
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Jakub, Would you be able to highlight you code and hit the code format button in the edit window.  Will make it a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling ICommandBar.CreateMacroItem, I'd [create a BaseMenu](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000049r000000) class at design time and populate it with Command progIDs.  Each VBA macro will need to be converted into a command - I'd [inherit BaseCommand](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000009000000) for those.  If you really do need dynamic menu's, have one of the commands [implement IMultiItem](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003vz000000).

Your ITool would use ICommandBars.Find to find the menu and call Popup on it.

I recommend putting all code within your mousedown handler within a [try/catch block](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000148000000).

Comment: Thanks Kirk. Also found snippets for this (Create Context Menu). Works as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used ArcObjects before but just by looking at the docs there is a [OnClick](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/ComponentHelp/esriCore/ICommand_OnClick.htm) event on the [Command](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/ComponentHelp/esriCore/ICommand.htm) for each [ICommandItem](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/ComponentHelp/esriCore/ICommandItem.htm) that `pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem` will return.

So I guess something like this would work:

```
Dim commandItem as ICommandItem 
commandItem = pContextMenu.CreateMacroItem(_
                                      "New Feature Class", _
                                      8, _
                                      "Normal.Module1.CreateNewFeatureClass")
Dim command as ICommand 
command = commandItem.Command
AddHandler command.OnClick, AddressOf Command_OnClick

Private Sub Command_OnClick()
  'In this example, a message box is displayed.
   MsgBox "Clicked on my command"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this once i figure out the first part of my problem which is the Select Tool itself. I'd like to be able to select features on the map just as i have done with the "VBA" tool but at the same time when the OnMouseDown event fires and receives the Button = 2 parameter (Right click instead of left) i would like to popup the context menu instead.

Answer (score 1):

you have to control it by OnContextMenu event.
you have to add an extension into your project.

[image]

then in context menu event you can control that if your tool is active, context menu popup else don't popup.

```
 Private Sub OnContextMenu(x As Integer, y As Integer, ByRef handled As Boolean)
    If YourCommandActiveCondition Then


        Dim pContextMenu As ICommandBar
        Dim commandBars As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars = m_application.Document.CommandBars
        pContextMenu = commandBars.Create("MyContextMenu", _
                           ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI.esriCmdBarType.esriCmdBarTypeShortcutMenu)

        ' Add 3 built in commands to the new context menu using the built in 
        ' ArcID module.
        Dim optionalIndex As System.Object = System.Type.Missing
        Dim uid As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass()

        uid.Value = "esriArcMapUI.ZoomInFixedCommand"
        ' Can use CLSID or ProgID
        uid.SubType = 0
        pContextMenu.Add(uid, optionalIndex)

        uid.Value = "{119591DB-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51}"
        ' Can use CLSID or ProgID
        uid.SubType = 1
        pContextMenu.Add(uid, optionalIndex)

        uid.Value = "{119591DB-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51}" ' export map
        ' Can use CLSID or ProgID
        uid.SubType = 2
        pContextMenu.Add(uid, optionalIndex)
        ' Popup the menu.
        pContextMenu.Popup()
        handled = True
        ' Let the application know that the OnContextMenu event was handled.
    End If
End Sub
```